# "Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null" when using Material UI Dialog

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

The moment i wrap "form" element with Material UI "Dialog", I get an "Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null" error, which makes it impossible for automatic width of InputLabel to work.

When i remove Dialog it works just fine and InputLabelRef is properly read on ComponentDidmount.

sandbox with example: https://codesandbox.io/s/1q98z07w13

I need it to be wrapped with Dialog. What might be the issue here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason that this is occurring is because the components inside of your dialog are not rendered when `componentDidMount` is called, even if your default state is `open === true`.

The trick here is to make sure that your form will always be mounted when `componentDidMount` is called. To do this you need to split your form out into a seperate component altogether that sits inside of your `Dialog` component. This way `componentDidMount` is called when the `Dialog` displays your seperate component and not when the `Dialog` itself has rendered.

I've updated your sandbox to include the changes I've mentioned: https://codesandbox.io/s/zw705046w3

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else who wants to **still use the outlined select without needing it to be rendered on mount**, you can just use Material UI's TextField component but pass it the `select` prop and label (as you normally would with other text fields). The offSetWidth label property is handled for you.

[Here's a working sandbox showing select but with the TextField wrapper.](https://qo5jd.codesandbox.io/)

Although I don't show it, you can take my word for it that if you render this post-mount it will not complain with any errors.

Comment: Your sandbox doesn't go to the code... just the results

Comment: What would you do if you wanted multiselect?

Comment: @lowcrawler, maybe you could try clicking on the **"Open Sandbox"** button on right hand - bottom corner?